# Can I set startRow to different values for different sheets using Maatwebsite's Laravel-Excel?

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel, phpdotenv

I'm using [Maatwebsite's Laravel-Excel](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs) to import an Excel file with two sheets. This file is generated by another system; I can't change the way it is produced.

On the first sheet, the first row is the column headings. This works fine.

[image: First sheet has headers in first row]

...but the second sheet has two rows of unwanted text, and then the headers in the *third* row.

[image: Second sheet has headers in third row]

I can set `config(['excel.import.startRow' => 3])` to start importing at the third row, but that means I miss the first two rows of useful data in the first sheet.

```
    config(['excel.import.startRow' => 3]);
    $sheets = $import->all();
```

Is there any way I can leave `excel.import.startRow` set to 1 for the first sheet, but set `excel.import.startRow` to 3 for the other sheet?

Comment: have you echo the data?

Comment: Yes. Normally, the data for People is fine but the data for Finance is broken - see https://jsfiddle.net/qurysp9r/

If I set `excel.import.startRow` to 3, then People is now broken because I skipped the first two rows including the header row - see https://jsfiddle.net/s1szqjnj/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStartRow;
```

In class:

```
class nameClass implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, WithStartRow
```

add the functions:

```
 public function headingRow(): int
{
    return 3;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function startRow(): int
{
    return 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've come up with an answer. It's not a *great* solution, but I guess it will do.

I will just import the whole document, and process the People tab and ignore the Finance tab.

Then I will set `excel.import.startRow` to 3 and import the whole document a second time, and this time I'll ignore the People tab and process the Finance tab.

Like I say this is not an elegant solution so if anyone comes up with a better way to do it I'd love to hear from you. But for now it will do.